# Find ".json" file from the 2nd level using regrex and node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, regex

I am trying to get the ".json" file from the second level nesting from the folderPath.

So suppose this is my `folderPath= "/user/admin/"` and I want to find if the second level nesting after contains a ".json" file or not

So I wrote a code but it is not helping to find the 2nd level ".json"

```js
function checkIfLastTwoLevelsAreJson(folderPath, filePath) {
    const fullPath = folderPath+ filePath;
    const regex = /^(?:\/[^/]+){2}\/[^/]+\.json$/; // Matches exactly two levels followed by .json
    return regex.test(fullPath);
}

const folderPath = "/user/admin";
const filePath1 = "en-us/dummy.json";
const filePath2 = "en-us/hello/dummy.json";
const filePath3 = "en-us/test/hello/dummy.json";

console.log(checkIfLastTwoLevelsAreJson(folderPath, filePath1)); // true
console.log(checkIfLastTwoLevelsAreJson(folderPath, filePath2)); // false
console.log(checkIfLastTwoLevelsAreJson(folderPath, filePath3)); // false
```

but here is the problem I am getting everything true it should have given me the first true and the rest false as the ".json" file containing at third or fourth level.

Can someone help me so I can get true only if the ".json" file is present in the 2nd level not in other levels?

Comment: All your examples return true because you get partial matches. You can prepend an anchor `^` to assert the start of the string like `^(?:\/[^/\n]+){2}\/[^/]+\.json$` See https://regex101.com/r/l4L4LW/1

Comment: I tried this and got this error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '^'" @Thefourthbird

Comment: I ran your example code with this line `const regex = /^(?:\/[^/]+){2}\/[^/]+\.json$/;` and it works for me.

Comment: Yes now I am getting every output as false  I am trying to get the first one true and the rest false

Comment: I can only see what is in the question, and when running all those examples it gives back what you expect. Are you running different code or did you change anything? If so, then please update the question with the code that is not working for you so readers can help you solve the issue at hand.

Comment: I am running the same code. If you see in the snippet I have added comments where I need true and where false. filepath1 will return true as it is in the 2nd level rest will return false as they are not in the 2nd level @Thefourthbird

Comment: Add `^` in the snippet in your question and then run the code, you will see that it works.